# ModuleNotFoundError in Connexion

Tags: python, openapi, connexion

I have an [OpenAPI 3.0](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification) specification and I want to use it with [Connexion](https://github.com/zalando/connexion) to run a Python service.

The relevant part of the API specification is here:

```
paths:
  /find:
    post:
      summary: XXX
      description: XXX
      operationId: service.controllers.api.find
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: object
              [...]
servers:
  - url: /v2
[...]
```

The Python code is structured like this:

```
├── lib
│   └── service
│       ├── controllers
│       │   ├── api.py
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── models
│       │   └── __init__.py
│       └── resources
│           └── openapi
│               └── openapi.yaml
```

The content of `api.py`:

```
def find():
    return "TEST"
```

The `find` function itself works as expected:

```
import service.controllers.api
service.controllers.api.find_skills()

'TEST'
```

In Python, Connexion loads the API fine:

```
import connexion
app = connexion.FlaskApp(__name__, 
specification_dir='lib/service/resources/openapi/')
app.add_api('openapi.yaml')                                                                                                

<connexion.apis.flask_api.FlaskApi at 0x7f2241e35b38>

app.run()
```

Now, I can call the endpoint with success:

```
$ curl -X POST http://localhost:5000/v2/find
```

However, when I run it using the [Connexion CLI](https://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli.html), I see a `ModuleNotFoundError`:

```
$ connexion run lib/service/resources/openapi/openapi.yaml
```

Output:

```
ERROR:connexion.apis.abstract:Failed to add operation for POST /v2/find
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/XXX/anaconda3/envs/find/lib/python3.6/site-packages/connexion/apis/abstract.py", line 206, in add_paths
    self.add_operation(path, method)
[...]
  File "/home/XXX/anaconda3/envs/find/lib/python3.6/site-packages/connexion/resolver.py", line 64, in resolve_function_from_operation_id
raise ResolverError(msg, sys.exc_info())
connexion.exceptions.ResolverError: <ResolverError: Cannot resolve operationId "service.controllers.api.find"! Import error was "No module named 'service'">
```

In this case, something is probably wrong with the paths/package names. However, I have also tried many variations of calling it from within the `lib` directory etc., but no luck. Also, I tried using the method name only and to specify the package in the `x-swagger-router-controller` property, but no luck either.

I could not find more specific details about how to specify the `operationId` correctly in the Connexion documentation, so I am not even clear if this is related to the Python module itself, to the OpenAPI specification, or to the way of calling Connexion.

Any hints on where to start digging?
Why does the command line client not find the `service` module? Where is the module supposed to reside relative to the working directory?

Comment: What does your OpenAPI doc (swagger.yaml?) say for `x-openapi-router-controller`? Btw JSON doesn't work as well as YAML in practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not reproduce your problem but I believe it happens due to the PYTHONPATH.

Try execute:

`PYTHONPATH=. connexion run lib/service/resources/openapi/openapi.yaml`